# Elements not properly aligned when trying to achieve simple CSS layout

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve this layout on my website (ignore the text underneath the picture):

[image]

I have tried to achieve it using this css and this html markup:

```css
header {
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  width: 97%;
  height: 25%;
}

section {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

aside {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: burlywood;
}

footer {
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: beige;
  width: 95%;
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Home</h1>
  <nav>
    <a href="./now.html">Now</a>
    <a href="./history.html">History</a>
    <a href="./future.html">Future</a>
  </nav>
</header>

<section>
  <article>
    <h4>article1</h4>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h4>article2</h4>
  </article>
</section>

<aside>
  <h4>aside</h4>
</aside>

<footer>
  <h4>footer</h4>
</footer>
```

The result is this:

[image]

You can see that the aside and header element are not aligned exactly. This is because I am using inline-block I think and there is some whitespace in the html file. Maybe there is a much simpler way to get the layout I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `section` and `aside` into `main` tag, and use flex to get the layout

```css
header {
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  width: 97%;
  height: 25%;
}

main {
  display: flex;
}

section {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

aside {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35%;
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: burlywood;
}

footer {
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: beige;
  width: 95%;
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Home</h1>
  <nav>
    <a href="./now.html">Now</a>
    <a href="./history.html">History</a>
    <a href="./future.html">Future</a>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  <section>
    <article>
      <h4>article1</h4>
    </article>

    <article>
      <h4>article2</h4>
    </article>
  </section>

  <aside>
    <h4>aside</h4>
  </aside>
</main>

<footer>
  <h4>footer</h4>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using grid layout or flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
 have had a quick play around, please refer to flexbox if it fits your purpose, note the footer is sticky and the articles change per content uniform with the aside.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background: blue; //just to show the container
}

header {
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  width: 97%;
  height: 25%;
}

section {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

aside {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35%;
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: burlywood;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: beige;
  width: 95%;
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Home</h1>
  <nav>
    <a href="./now.html">Now</a>
    <a href="./history.html">History</a>
    <a href="./future.html">Future</a>
  </nav>
</header>
<main class="container">
<section>
  <article>
    <h4>article1</h4>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h4>article2</h4>
    <p>Auto-layout for flexbox grid columns also means you can set the width of one column and have the sibling columns automatically resize around it. You may use predefined grid classes (as shown below), grid mixins, or inline widths. Note that the other columns will resize no matter the width of the center column.<p/>
  </article>
</section>

<aside>
  <h4>aside</h4>
</aside>
</main>

<footer>
  <h4>footer</h4>
</footer>
```

Comment: you will need to implement relevant @media queries for responsive layouts.